# Express this in terms of conditional probabilities and express this in terms of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

Let $N$ equal the number of time a certain device may be used before it breaks. The probability is $p$ that it will break on any one try given that it did not break on any of the previous tries.

(a) Express this in terms of conditional probabilities.

I'm confused I have two interpretations, but What is the correct?

Let $s$ the  number of future tries and let $t$ the previous tries (the device  did not break)

$Pr( t < X < t+s | X > t) = p$

or

$Pr( X  > t+s | X > t) = p$

(b) Express it in terms of a density function, and find the density funtion

Can Someone  help me there??  Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I would say that for part (a), you're looking for
$$
P(N=t+1\mid N>t)=p.
$$
That is, the probability that it breaks on the $(t+1)$-st attempt to use it, given that it did not break in the first $t$, is $p$.

I don't want to make any comment on a density function here, however; this is, as stated, a discrete process -- so, you could talk about its mass function, but it shouldn't have a density.  Unless there are further assumptions here that aren't stated?

Comment: No, it's my complete exercise my book says this (Introduction to the thoery of statistics Alexander Mood) but I think the book referred to mass function. Thanks you so much